# Append json data to HTML List box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

HTML code is :

```
<select  name="ser" id="ser" class="form-control" onchange="getPrice(this.value);">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Value11">Value1</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
</select>
<select  name="freeitem" id="freeitem" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Js Code :

```
function getPrice(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_sales_price.php',
    data: {
      get_option: val
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      $('#freeitem').html(response.fritm);

    }
  });
}
```

and Php Code is :

```
$option = $_POST['get_option'];
    $data = array(); 
    $prdqty = $db->execute("select product_name from master_purchase where product_code='$option' and delet='0'");
    while ($tqty = $prdqty->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $data['fritm'] = '<option value="'.$tqty['product_name'].'">'.$tqty['product_name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

while we selecting first selectbox content, need to add some data to second select box from database, we almost done the things but the second select box didn't show any values ,please help us to resolve the above problem

Comment: i try this its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with some hard code value and it perfectly working fine:-

Html+Jquery (in single page with .html extension):-

```
<select  name="ser" id="ser" class="form-control" onchange="getPrice(this.value);">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Value11">Value1</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
</select>
<select  name="freeitem" id="freeitem" class="form-control">
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script><!-- added jquery library-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPrice(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_sales_price.php',
    data: {
      get_option: val
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      $('#freeitem').html(response.fritm);

    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Php (with hard-coded value):-

```
<?php
$option = $_POST['get_option'];
$data = array(); 
$data['fritm'] = ''; // you need to define it as empty string first
for($i = 0;$i<10;$i++) // hard-code started
{
$data['fritm'] .= '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'; // append each option to the string one-by-one and check `.=` also
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Output:-

http://prntscr.com/auyn7i

http://prntscr.com/auymzf

http://prntscr.com/auynij

Note:- problem may be occuring because either you missed jquery library of concatenation inside loop or some other error in your php file.

Comment: Please take care of comments also.

Comment: its work.. but some problems. when I select an item in a list box its corresponding value appear in the second select box, I select any other item in the first select box its value appears with previously appeared results.

Comment: No it will not because `.html` will replace previous html first and then add next html. what you are telling that will happen when you use `.append`. So check that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1) concatenate results in while loop. You are re-assigning the array variable causing latest one to overwrite the old one.
This way, only old value will be appended.

Change

```
$data['fritm'] = '<option value="'.$tqty['product_name'].'">'.$tqty['product_name'].'</option>';
```

To

```
$data['fritm'] .= '<option value="'.$tqty['product_name'].'">'.$tqty['product_name'].'</option>';
```

2) Change

```
$('#freeitem').html(response.fritm);
```

To

```
$('#freeitem').append(response.fritm);
```

As you are just appending options to drop down, not changing its HTML.

Comment: See firebug's console and observe what is the response.

Comment: i pass another some variables : - $data['price'] = $pprce['sale_price'];
$data['tax'] = $pprce['tax_amt'];
$data['avalqty'] = $total_stkqty; and $data['fritm']

Comment: can you add screenshot of your php code and js code